# Си Строки. Программа перестает работать после того, как в строке появляется "пробел"

Tags: c, строки

Задание:

> Написать программу, которая будет проверять символы в строке после
>   точки, и если там стоит строчная буква заменять ее на прописную.

Если после точки сразу стоит буква, то программа работает, а если буква
стоит после точки и пробела, то перестает работать. Никакой ошибки не
пишет.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int i, n;
    printf("Введите длину строки : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char stroka[n];
    printf("Введите строку : \n");
    scanf("%s", stroka);
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(stroka); i++)
    {
        if(stroka[i] == '.')
        {
            if(stroka[i + 1] == ' ')
                stroka[i + 2] = toupper(stroka[i + 2]);
            else
                stroka[i + 1] = toupper(stroka[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    printf("%s", stroka);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "перестает работать"? Выдает не тот результат что вы ожидаете? Приведите что вводите, что ожидаете и что выдает

Comment: Я же скрин приложил. Если после точки пробел идёт, то он строку просто не читает дальше, а должен букву строчную преобразовать

Comment: Попробуйте сразу после ввода до преобразования вывести введенную строку и ее длину. Есть ли вообще в строке то, что вы ввели после пробела?

Comment: Действительно, после пробела ничего не вводится. Почему так?

Comment: Потому, что scanf всегда читает только до первого пробельного символа, подробности в документации, например тут http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: До перевода каретки (enter) или конца входного буфера читает `gets`

Comment: Еще несколько замечаний по пограничным случаям. 1) Для строки длины N нужно N+1 байт, в последнем будет храниться терминатор `\0`. 2) При `i == strlen(stroka)-1` обращение к элементам `stroka[i+1]` и `stroka[i+2]` мягко говоря не безопасны.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Нет больше такой буквы в этом слове - `gets` убрана из стандарта. Есть `fgets` или `gets_s`.

Answer (score 1):

Введите переменную текущего состояния. Например, она может быть равна 0 вначале, и меняться на 1, если встречена точка, и на 0, если буква. Пробел ничего не меняет.

```
Если встречена точка:
     состояние = 1
Если встречена буква:
     Состояние 1 ?  
          поменять её на строчную. 
          Состояние = 0
```

Comment: А как записать « если встречена буква»?

Comment: @George Зависит от того, что считать буквой. Например,  `isalpha()`, если этот [макрос](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/isalpha) доступен, или что-то вроде `if(stroka[i] >= 'A' &&  stroka[i] <= 'z')` или